# as3 FLV component posistion / align issue - FLVPlayback();

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, alignment, flvplayback

**ATTEMPTING:**

I am trying to load a FLV using the FLVPlayback() component in another dynamic mc and place it on a TV screen.

**ISSUE:**

---It won't load at the Top left.
---It scales to fit the WIDTH to the fit the TV screen but there this funky space below and above.

**QUESTIONS:**

How can I place the video at the top left? How can I make it fit the HEIGHT of the TV Screen?

**CODE:**

```
import flash.display.*;
import fl.video.*;

var my_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); 
addChild(my_mc); 

var myVideo:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
myVideo.source = "http://EdVizenor.com/edgen/EpicLogo.flv";
myVideo.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT; /// This does not work :(
my_mc.addChild(myVideo);

One.BlackScreen.addChild(my_mc);
my_mc.width = One.BlackScreen.width;
my_mc.height = One.BlackScreen.height;

...
```

**FLA SOURCE DOWNLOAD**

The Source FLA file is here: http://www.edvizenor.com/Help.fla
It has the images and TV screen etc...

**UPDATE ISSUE: 4/21/12**

The answer below is correct but when I use this video source and do not change anything else then I have the same issue. How can I fix this?

```
myVideo.source = "http://EdVizenor.com/Boom.flv"; /// DOES NOT WORK
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your .flv file isn't the same ratio as your movieclip.

```
import flash.display.*;
import fl.video.*;

var my_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); 
addChild(my_mc); 

var myVideo:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
myVideo.source = "http://EdVizenor.com/edgen/EpicLogo.flv";
myVideo.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
myVideo.scaleMode = VideoScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
myVideo.width = One.BlackScreen.width;
myVideo.height = One.BlackScreen.height;

my_mc.addChild(myVideo);
myVideo.play();

One.BlackScreen.addChild(my_mc);
my_mc.width = One.BlackScreen.width;
my_mc.height = One.BlackScreen.height;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thats it! I figured it out too on my own. I have one line slightly differnt but it works. Thanks my friend!!! :)

Comment: WAIT... so I try this video with the EXACT same code you used with the other video and it does the same problem. Here is the link: myVideo.source = "http:// EdVizenor.com/Boom.flv"; I had to put a space in the URL here.

Comment: I found another issue. I posted it in my first post at the very bottom.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the new video has a blank strip actually encoded within the movie. i.e.e the movie size might be 800x450 but the actual rendered area is only 800x400. You can test this by using addChild(myVideo) directly onto the stage, or by playing the Boom.flv in a standalone flv player

Comment: Well you are on the right path about the video. Its a coding issue. Not sure but the flv took on a 1.00 something and the video I brought in before was not that. Interesting.